# How substr_replace array values shorter?

Tags: php

After unsuccessfully  searching through the web. Here is my problem.

I want to change some values on different array values and not change the name of the array like.

```
$arr = array('Example1','Example2','Example3');
$arr2 = array('Value1','Value2','Value3');

$arr[0]  = substr_replace($arr[0], 'X', -1, 1); 
$arr[2]  = substr_replace($arr[2], 'X', -1, 1); 
$arr2[1] = substr_replace($arr2[1], 'X', -1, 1); 
$arr2[2] = substr_replace($arr2[2], 'X', -1, 1);
```

How to short all the substr_replace lines? I think I need a loop.

Comment: The loop wouldn't make sense in this case because you're avoiding certain keys from the array, and then you would just end up with a bunch of if statements resulting in several more lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
If you will change every values, use <del>foreach</del> for loop
If you will change only some known strings, use function:

```
function rpl($arr,$a){
    return substr_replace($arr[$a],'X',-1,1);
}
```

then usage:

```
$arr[0]=rpl($arr,0);
$arr[2]=rpl($arr,2);
$arr2[1]=rpl($arr2,1);
$arr2[2]=rpl($arr2,2);
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I was hoping for a really short solution

Comment: Can you please show me also the a foreach example, if I want change every value of an array? I have now a solution in which the start postion is also a variable of the function. I'm also searching for a multibyte version of `substr_replace` like `mb_substr` for `substr`

Answer (score 1):

If you want change everything in array, you can pass array instead of string to substr_replace

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

example:

```
$arr=substr_replace($arr,'X',-1,1);
```

If you want to do with loop:
For changing values in array using foreach is actually complicated (which I realized later)
using normal loop is better here

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    $arr[$i]=substr_replace($arr[$i],'X',-1,1);
```